# When is Christmas on Mars?

Tags: mars, santa-claus

The question, [Will Santa Claus deliver presents to Mars in 2025?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/will-santa-claus-deliver-presents-to-mars-in-2025) got me thinking.

There are 24 well documented zones on earth, of when Christmas occurs. Does Christmas on Mars, come before, during or after Christmas on Earth?

[Santa's 1998 interview with NASA](http://science1.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/1998/ast24dec98_1/) Suggests there is only one Christmas per Mars year, but the specific date is not mentioned.  Presumably it would be timed near the martian [Winter solstice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_solstice), but I really have no idea.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about observance of religious holidays on days of the liturgical calendar, and not about topics within the scope of [space.se], as defined in our [About] and [Help] pages.

Comment: This movie reveals the answer. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058548/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Christmas on Earth is essentially a winter solstice holiday. Its date was fixed based on the Roman winter solstice (a southern solstice) which was December 25th.

*(Note: Southern solstice is the time of the year when the sun is at its southernmost point in the sky. It is independent of hemisphere, whereas winter/summer solstices are north/south dependent. All winter solstices in the Northern hemisphere are southern solstices.)*

It only makes sense that if Santa is doing Christmas on Mars once a Martian year, that he would also use the Martian southern solstice.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130516125740/http://pweb.jps.net/~tgangale/mars/mst/WinterSolstice.htm) is a chart of winter solstice times on Mars from 1875 to 2127. It appears that the next winter solstice on Mars after Mars One is scheduled to arrive is April 25, 2026. I assume that these are southern solstices.

If this is when Santa plans on delivering gifts to Mars, this will give him plenty of time after Earth's Christmas.

However, there is also the possibility that Santa will continue to use December 25 because of its convention. If this is the case, he will have to abandon his plans of only visiting Mars once per Martian year.

**[More on Martian timekeeping on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars#Martian_year)**